# I need to use multiple conditions in a while statement

Tags: python, loops

I am new to coding and I have very little idea as to what I am doing. So this may be very wrong. But I have to create a code that determines slope and the Y intercept. I created a loop to determine if any coordinates are the same and if they are they must be changed, however I am having trouble getting out of the loop. Here is my current loop. Any help would be appreciated greatly! Thanks in advance!

```
def whileloop():

while True:
    y1 == y2 or x1 == x2


    print ("Error")




            print("please enter values that are not equal to eachother.")
            y1_str = input ("please enter y1: ")
            y2_str = input ("please enter y2: ")



            print ("please enter values that are not equal to eachother.")
            x1_str = input ("please enter x1: ")
            x2_str = input ("please enter x2: ")


else: y1!= y2 or x1!=x2
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting, first of all.

Comment: Anyway, the first problem is that you have a `while True` and you don't have a `break` (or `return`) anywhere, so of course the loop is going to go forever. If you want to `break` out of it at some point, you have to do something like `if <reason to break>: break`.

Comment: Next, `y1 == y2 or x1 == x2` is just an expression. Whether it's true or false doesn't matter, because you ignore the value of it. You may have wanted an `if` statement here: `if y1 == y2 or x1 == x2:`. Then, the code inside that `if` statement (indented to the right of it) will only run if the expression is true.

Comment: Next, an `else:` attached to a `while` loop runs only when the loop expression becomes false. So, for `while True:`, it will never run (even if you `break` out of the loop).

Comment: Next, you never assign anything to `y1`, `y2`, `x1`, or `x2` anywhere, and you can't usefully compare things that don't exist. The fact that you've assigned strings to similarly-named variables like `y1_str` doesn't mean Python can magically figure out what you want `y1` to be.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want is something like this:

```
def whileloop():
    while True:
        y1_str = input("please enter y1: ")
        y2_str = input("please enter y2: ")
        x1_str = input("please enter x1: ")
        x2_str = input("please enter x2: ")
        y1 = float(y1_str)
        y2 = float(y2_str)
        x1 = float(x1_str)
        x2 = float(x2_str)

        if y1 == y2 or x1 == x2:
            print("please enter values that are not equal to eachother.")
        else:
            return y1, y2, x1, x2
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to use multiple conditions in a while/if/elif statement is pretty simple.  Something like this works fine

```
while A and B:

while A or B: 

while A and not B:

while (A and B) or C:
```

etc

The possibilities are endless - just make sure to clearly define each condition, and if in doubt separate conditions with parentheses for clarity.  For your code specifically

```
while y1 == y2 or x1 == x2:
    print("please enter values that are not equal to eachother.")

    y1_str = input("please enter y1: ")
    y2_str = input("please enter y2: ")
    x1_str = input("please enter x1: ")
    x2_str = input("please enter x2: ")

    y1 = float(y1_str)
    y2 = float(y2_str)
    x1 = float(x1_str)
    x2 = float(x2_str)


# Do stuff with y1, y2, x1, x2
```

This method requires you to already have `y1`, `y2`, `x1` and `x2` defined - if you want to define them in the while loop then abarnert's method will will work quite well